# How to know if a paper is reviewed in zbMATH database?

Tags: mathematics, databases

So I wonder how one can differentiate if the work is reviewed or pending in the zbMATH database. In MathSciNet, it is clearly, mentioned if the work is prelim, pending, reviewed or indexed. But in zbMATH, there is no information like that. If the report is given then there is a name of the reviewer with the name of the city beside the item otherwise we are unaware if it is in review or indexed or only the summary has been selected as review.

Comment: Did you ask the people of zbMATH?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth That's a good idea, I will ask them. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the following response from zbMATH (Mr. David Biesenack) and it clears my doubt.

"If a paper/book will be reviewed will be
decided by our section editors in charge individually. You can see
according to the item id if a paper is still in the process or already
finalized (e.g. Zbl 07674133 is still unfinished / Zbl 1441.60053 is
finalized)."

P.S. I am not deleting the question as it might be helpful to others for future reference.

Comment: Indeed, please don't delete the question. I was wondering about the same thing and am happy that you asked and shared the reply here.